# Draw vertical line after n data points in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph drawn with d3 with the x and y scales defined as follows:

```
x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30, 150]).range([0, width])
y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0])
```

I need to draw a vertical line after 25% of data points. So I have my code like this:

```
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', lowerLimit)
  .attr('y1', 0)
  .attr('x2', lowerLimit)
  .attr('y2', height)
  .style('stroke', 'red')
```

My problem is I am not sure how to set the `lowerLimit` x value to be 25% of all the x-values in the scale. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Can you make a jsfiddle of what you are doing? or print the data you are trying to draw?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is not clear. When you say:

> I need to draw a vertical line after 25% of data points

You're talking about [the first quartile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile), which is **impossible** to calculate without the data, and not only that, but which **changes** for every different data set.

If you are indeed talking about the first quartile, this is what you have to do:

Given an data array called `data`, you can use [d3.quantile](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#quantile):

```
var firstQuartile = d3.quantile(data, 0.25);
```

In the following demo, I'm plotting 100 dots, and calculating the 25 percentile (first quartile) regarding the property `x`:

```
var lowerLimit = d3.quantile(data, 0.25, function(d) {
    return d.x
});
```

The console shows the value. Check the demo:

```js
var data = d3.range(100).map(() => ({
    x: Math.random() * 120 + 30,
    y: Math.random() * 100
}));

var w = 500,
    h = 160;
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30, 150]).range([20, w - 20]);
y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([h - 20, 20]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.y));

var data = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.x, b.x))

var lowerLimit = d3.quantile(data, 0.25, function(d) {
    return d.x
});

console.log(lowerLimit);

svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', x(lowerLimit))
    .attr('y1', 20)
    .attr('x2', x(lowerLimit))
    .attr('y2', h - 20)
    .style('stroke', 'red')

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - 20) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you're talking about *"getting the value that is 25% of the domain"*, the answer is easy. You can, for instance, create a function:

```
function findLimit(percentage) {
    return x(x.domain()[0] + (x.domain()[1] - x.domain()[0]) * percentage / 100);
};
```

And pass the value of that function to `lowerLimit`:

```
var lowerLimit = findLimit(25);
```

Check this demo, drawing a line at 25% of the x axis:

```js
var data = d3.range(100).map(() => ({
    x: Math.random() * 120 + 30,
    y: Math.random() * 100
}));

var w = 500,
    h = 200;
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30, 150]).range([20, w - 20]);
y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([h - 20, 20]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.y));

var data = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.x, b.x))

var lowerLimit = d3.quantile(data, 0.25, function(d) {
    return d.x
});

console.log(lowerLimit);

svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', x(lowerLimit))
    .attr('y1', 20)
    .attr('x2', x(lowerLimit))
    .attr('y2', h - 20)
    .style('stroke', 'red')

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - 20) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```